# Cross domain iframe - change checkbox state

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an Iframe I'm embedding in the site. It's from another domain. It has two checkboxes but I need to change the default checked to unchecked and the unchecked one to checked.

Is there any smart way of doing this via JS / jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the the iframe domain is NOT under Your control, meaning You cannot modify the code on the server, there is nothing You can do. Script access is not allowed due to security restrictions.

IF You can modify the iframe code, I guess `postMessage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) would be the right way to communicate with the iframe.

Comment: If you don't have access to modify the page that is inside the iframe, you could try setup a reverse proxy to that page (and all it's resources...) so that for the browser it will appear as both pages (inside and outside of iframe) come from the same domain. Then you will have unrestricted javascript access (through iFrameObject.contentWindow.document).